# Error unexpected char: '\' or unexpected token when using sed regex in groovy function

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, sed

I have a sed regular expression that parses all dockerfiles in the current and sub directory and adds my registy to the image name if it's not there. I need to add it to the grooves function which is called in jenkinsfile. When adding I get: either unexpected token or unexpected char errors.  Although in the Linux console, the expression works well.
My regex:

```
for d in `find . -name '*Dockerfile*'`; do 
sed -i -e '/^FROM my[.]own[.]registy[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.own.registy.org\//' $d; 
done
```

Trying to integrate it into the groovy.
via shell:

```
def call (Here is a function that downloads dockerfiles from the repository)
    ---
    ---
    sh "for d in `find . -name '*Dockerfile*'`; do sed -i -e '/^FROM my[.]own[.]registy[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.own.registy.org\//' $d; done"
```

I am getting an error (with a pointer to the escape character after my.own.registy.org):

unexpected token: for @ line 38, column 22. def sedCommand = for d in `find . -name '*Dockerfile*'`; do sed -i -e '/^FROM my[.]own[.]registy[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.own.registy.org\//' $d; done

If I try with a function:

```
def call (Here is a function that downloads dockerfiles from the repository)
    ---
    ---
    def sedCommand = for d in `find . -name '*Dockerfile*'`; do sed -i -e '/^FROM my[.]own[.]registy[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.own.registy.org\//' $d; done
```

Then I get an error(with a pointer to last appostrophe ' symbol):
unexpected token: for @ line 38, column 22. def sedCommand = for d in `find . -name '*Dockerfile*'`; do sed -i -e '/^FROM my[.]own[.]registy[.]org/{p;d}' -e 's/^FROM /FROM my.own.registy.org\//' $d; done

How can I fix this?
Or how can i do the same regex for grooves? Unfortunately I don't know groovy very well

Comment: Why not just use groovy to do it instead of forking sed processes?

Comment: unfortunately I don't know groovy very well

Comment: what is `sh` - is this for jenkins? Then you should tag this accordingly

Comment: yes, this is for jenkins. added information

Comment: found a solution. used an alternative delimiter for sed |